# python linear equation with Cramer's rule

Tags: python, linear-algebra

I'm new to python and attempting to write a linear equation using Cramer's Rule. I've entered the formula and have code prompting user to enter a,b,c,d,e and f but my code is getting a syntax error. I'd like to fix the code and also have a system for researching and correcting future errors.

```
a,b,c,d,e,f = float(input("Enter amount: ")

a*x + by = e
cx + dy = f
x = ed-bf/ad-bc
y=af-ed/ad-bc

if (ad - bc == 0)print("The equation has no solution")

else print ("x=" x, "y=" y,)
```

Comment: you can use "try" and "except" for error handling; they must be used in pairs

Comment: Thank you. Where would I place "try" and "except" relative to error/code?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/hM7BdgdP; put your code to attempt to do a thing in the "try", and if that results in a normal python error, then the code will execute the "except" part, assuming that that will not result in en error either.

Comment: I would really recommend you to go through some basic tutorial, like https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/

Comment: it's that bad. lol. ok, thank you.

Comment: @crazicrafter1 You can not catch syntax errors.

Comment: @Th... That's why you correct any syntax before executing the code, otherwise python will yell at you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, your code was one giant syntax error. Please read some basic tutorial, as was suggested in the comments. Hopefully this will help in the learning process (I didn't go through the actual math formulas):

```
a = float(input("Enter a: "))
b = float(input("Enter b: "))
c = float(input("Enter c: "))
d = float(input("Enter d: "))
e = float(input("Enter e: "))
f = float(input("Enter f: "))

##a*x + by = e
##cx + dy = f

if (a*d - b*c == 0):
    print("The equation has no solution")
else:
    x = (e*d-b*f)/(a*d-b*c)
    y = (a*f-e*d)/(a*d-b*c)

    print ("x=%s" % x, "y=%s" % y)
```

You have to put `*` between the numbers you want to multiply. You had one parenthesis missing from your input statement. The equations themselves are commented out, because otherwise Python takes them as a code (incorrectly written one). You have to enclose the denominator in parentheses because math. You have to end the `if`, `else`, `elif`, `for`, `while` and such with `:`. Indentation is VERY important in Python.

Comment: yeah i was gonna say something seemed off the rocker with 5 variables referring to 1 input, and with the remaining code

Comment: You should put `if (a*d - b*c == 0):` before `x = (e*d-b*f)/(a*d-b*c)`, or you'll get `ZeroDivisionError` exception